# extract http body from http response

Tags: c, httpresponse, pcap, extract, tcp

I have written a program that take a .pcap file that is an output of wireshark capture and contains response of an image request. my program has to gather the http body data from the packets and append all of them to a file. but sth wrong happens here:
the size of body data for each packet, which is written to the file is less than its real body data size. 
I can see that header.caplen and header.len are the same.
in my code there is totally 54 byte (14 ethernet+ 20 tcp+ 20 ip) for header part of each packet but strlen(payload) is less than (header.len - 54)

here is my structures:

```
/* Ethernet addresses are 6 bytes */
#define ETHER_ADDR_LEN  6

    struct sniff_ethernet {
        u_char ether_dhost[ETHER_ADDR_LEN]; /* Destination host address */
        u_char ether_shost[ETHER_ADDR_LEN]; /* Source host address */
        u_short ether_type; /* IP? ARP? RARP? etc */
    };

    /* IP header */
    struct sniff_ip {
        u_char ip_vhl;      /* version << 4 | header length >> 2 */
        u_char ip_tos;      /* type of service */
        u_short ip_len;     /* total length */
        u_short ip_id;      /* identification */
        u_short ip_off;     /* fragment offset field */
    #define IP_RF 0x8000        /* reserved fragment flag */
    #define IP_DF 0x4000        /* dont fragment flag */
    #define IP_MF 0x2000        /* more fragments flag */
    #define IP_OFFMASK 0x1fff   /* mask for fragmenting bits */
        u_char ip_ttl;      /* time to live */
        u_char ip_p;        /* protocol */
        u_short ip_sum;     /* checksum */
        struct in_addr ip_src,ip_dst; /* source and dest address */
    };
    #define IP_HL(ip)       (((ip)->ip_vhl) & 0x0f)
    #define IP_V(ip)        (((ip)->ip_vhl) >> 4)

    /* TCP header */
    typedef u_int tcp_seq;

    struct sniff_tcp {
        u_short th_sport;   /* source port */
        u_short th_dport;   /* destination port */
        tcp_seq th_seq;     /* sequence number */
        tcp_seq th_ack;     /* acknowledgement number */
        u_char th_offx2;    /* data offset, rsvd */
    #define TH_OFF(th)  (((th)->th_offx2 & 0xf0) >> 4)
        u_char th_flags;
    #define TH_FIN 0x01
    #define TH_SYN 0x02
    #define TH_RST 0x04
    #define TH_PUSH 0x08
    #define TH_ACK 0x10
    #define TH_URG 0x20
    #define TH_ECE 0x40
    #define TH_CWR 0x80
    #define TH_FLAGS (TH_FIN|TH_SYN|TH_RST|TH_ACK|TH_URG|TH_ECE|TH_CWR)
        u_short th_win;     /* window */
        u_short th_sum;     /* checksum */
        u_short th_urp;     /* urgent pointer */
};
```

and here is my main function:

```
/* ethernet headers are always exactly 14 bytes */
#define SIZE_ETHERNET 14

    const struct sniff_ethernet *ethernet; /* The ethernet header */
    const struct sniff_ip *ip; /* The IP header */
    const struct sniff_tcp *tcp; /* The TCP header */
//  const char *payload; /* Packet payload */

    u_int size_ip;
    u_int size_tcp;

    char *img_body;
    FILE *img;

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {

    char *file = "/home/test1/app-engine1/right/r_response.pcap";
    pcap_t *pcap;
    const unsigned char *packet;
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    struct pcap_pkthdr header;
    u_char *payload = (u_char*) malloc(sizeof(u_char) * 3000);
    int counter = 0;
    int real_len = 0;
    img = fopen("/home/test1/app-engine1/img", "wa");


    pcap = pcap_open_offline(file, errbuf);
    if (pcap == NULL)
    {
            fprintf(stderr, "error reading pcap file: %s\n", errbuf);
            return 1;
    }    


    while((packet = pcap_next(pcap, &header)) != NULL){
        counter++;
        ethernet = (struct sniff_ethernet*)(packet);

        ip = (struct sniff_ip*)(packet + SIZE_ETHERNET);

        printf("len=%d, eth_type=%d, protocol=%d\n", header.caplen, ethernet->ether_type, ip->ip_p);

        size_ip = IP_HL(ip)*4;

        usleep(1e5);

        if (size_ip < 20) 
        {
                printf("   * Invalid IP header length: %u bytes\n", size_ip);
                continue;
            }

        tcp = (struct sniff_tcp*)(packet + SIZE_ETHERNET + size_ip);

        size_tcp = TH_OFF(tcp)*4;

        if (size_tcp < 20) 
        {
                printf("   * Invalid TCP header length: %u bytes\n", size_tcp);
                continue;
            }
        strcpy(payload, (u_char *)(packet + SIZE_ETHERNET + size_ip + size_tcp));
            if(strlen(payload) <= 0)
                continue;
        real_len += strlen(payload);
        printf("caplen:%d       len:%d     strlen(payload):%u\n", header.caplen, header.len, strlen(payload));
        fwrite(payload, strlen(payload), 1, img);

    }
    fclose(img);
    printf("counter:%d  real_len:%d\n", counter, real_len);
}
```

Comment: Don't use strlen on binary data, they might contain `\0` end thus mark the end of the string. Also don't use strcpy which has the same problem.

Comment: tnx...I think I have to replace "strlen(payload)" with "header.len"....I will give that a try.